# Using Find in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to use `.find()` like this for mongoDB in Python :

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27000')
db = client['responsi']
cursor = db['produk']

for x in cursor.find({"pricing.pct_savings":{"$gt":25}}).sort({"pricing.pct_savings":-1}):
    print(x)
```

But, it showing error like this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Find.py", line 7, in <module>
    for x in cursor.find({"pricing.pct_savings":{"$gt":25}}).sort({"pricing.pct_savings":-1}):
  File "G:\PROGRAM FILES\Python\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 708, in sort
    keys = helpers._index_list(key_or_list, direction)
  File "G:\PROGRAM FILES\Python\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 69, in _index_list
    raise TypeError("if no direction is specified, "
TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list
```

How to solved this problem?
Thank you!
Sorry, I have bad score in english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As opposed to the mongo shell, pymongo takes `key` and `direction` as the arguments to the sort method (or list, but that's another form that is not relevant to you currently, I'll show it too)
So your query should actually be `cursor.find({"pricing.pct_savings":{"$gt":25}}).sort("pricing.pct_savings", pymongo.DESCENDING)`

The other form gets a list of tuples of field name and the direction, and allows you to sort by multiple fields, for example `collection.find().sort([('my_field_1',pymongo.DESCENDING), ('my_field_2',pymongo.ASCENDING)])`

See the relevant documentation here https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html?highlight=sort#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.sort

You can find the `ASCENDING` and `DESCENDING` constants here https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.ASCENDING

BTW (not related to your original question)
`db['produk']` is actually a collection, not a cursor, so it would be better if you would call it collection, and not cursor.
Cursor is what `find()` returns

Comment: Thank you!, its work... And, for the `db` and `cursor`, i forgot to change it.. This isvery helpful..

Answer (score 0):

should only have this structure

```
from bson import ObjectId
id = '375g68h97b680jf78j'
data = cursor.find_one_and_delete({'_id': ObjectId(id)})
```